# Looker Studio - Combining Dimensions and Metrics

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have this interactive metric that sums up the time and classifies it so that depending on the classification filter, it varies between in or out. This works fine in a table, but I can't add it to a bar chart. Can someone help me? Thanks.

CASE
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm = 'SL1' THEN tiempo_grupoH END) <=3 THEN 'IN'
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm = 'SL1' THEN tiempo_grupoH END) >3 THEN 'OUT'
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm = 'SL2' THEN tiempo_grupoH END) <=12 THEN 'IN'
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm = 'SL2' THEN tiempo_grupoH END) >12 THEN 'OUT'
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm IN ('SL3','SL4') THEN tiempo_grupoH END) <=24 THEN 'IN'
WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN clasificacion IS NOT NULL AND priority_name_norm IN ('SL3','SL4') THEN tiempo_grupoH END) >24 THEN 'OUT'

END

This works fine in a table, but I can't add it to a bar chart

Comment: I think you need an ELSE statement at the end of the code

Comment: The formula is using aggregation (`sum`) and returns a dimension (string). This is not allowed for a looker-studio formula. Can this calculation be done in an custom BigQuery? Can you change the output from string to a number? IN=1, OUT=2? Create a blend and you can use the aggregated value as a dimension.